# Is there any built in C# function to convert number to word

Tags: c#-3.0

Optimal solution to convert a number to word in C#?
For Example -
Number = 100
Corresponding word = Hundred

Is there any built in function in C#?
If yes how can i use it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are wanting the word to equal the value, but if you are then this would be a solution. If not then search for "numbers to word value c#" and that'll come up with some other possible solutions or "How can I convert a number into its verbal representation?" I didn't see anything in any of the C# libraries, yet so that would be interesting. I see a lot of if statements or Switch Case statements on MSDN. After doing some research and view examples provided here is what I was able to successfully execute.

```
using System;

namespace ObjectMoneyExample
{
    public class Money
    {
        // Fields
        private decimal paycheck;

        // Empty Constuctor
        public Money(decimal numbers) 
        {
            paycheck = numbers;
        }

        // Paycheck proerties
        
        public decimal Paycheck
        {
            get { return paycheck; }
            set { paycheck = value; }
        }
    }

    // Following Class & Method Based on Example provided
    // by https://stackoverflow.com/users/832136/hannele
    public class FromNumbers
    {
        private string[] ones = {
        "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine",
        "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen",
        };

        private static string[] tens = { "zero", "ten", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety" };

        private static string[] thous = { "hundred", "thousand", "million", "billion", "trillion", "quadrillion" };

        private static string fmt_negative = "negative {0}";
        private static string fmt_dollars_and_cents = "{0} dollars and {1} cents";
        private static string fmt_tens_ones = "{0}-{1}"; // e.g. for twenty-one, thirty-two etc. You might want to use an en-dash or em-dash instead of a hyphen.
        private static string fmt_large_small = "{0} {1}"; // stitches together the large and small part of a number, like "{three thousand} {five hundred forty two}"
        private static string fmt_amount_scale = "{0} {1}"; // adds the scale to the number, e.g. "{three} {million}";

        public string ToWords(decimal number)
        {
            if (number < 0)
                return string.Format(fmt_negative, ToWords(Math.Abs(number)));

            int intPortion = (int)number;
            int decPortion = (int)((number - intPortion) * (decimal)100);

            return string.Format(fmt_dollars_and_cents, ToWords(intPortion), ToWords(decPortion));
        }

        private string ToWords(int number, string appendScale = "")
        {
            string numString = "";
            // if the number is less than one hundred, then we're mostly just pulling out constants from the ones and tens dictionaries
            if (number < 100)
            {
                if (number < 20)
                    numString = ones[number];
                else
                {
                    numString = tens[number / 10];
                    if ((number % 10) > 0)
                        numString = string.Format(fmt_tens_ones, numString, ones[number % 10]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                int pow = 0; // we'll divide the number by pow to figure out the next chunk
                string powStr = ""; // powStr will be the scale that we append to the string e.g. "hundred", "thousand", etc.

                if (number < 1000)
                { // number is between 100 and 1000
                    pow = 100; // so we'll be dividing by one hundred
                    powStr = thous[0]; // and appending the string "hundred"
                }
                else
                { // find the scale of the number
                  // log will be 1, 2, 3 for 1_000, 1_000_000, 1_000_000_000, etc.
                    int log = (int)Math.Log(number, 1000);
                    // pow will be 1_000, 1_000_000, 1_000_000_000 etc.
                    pow = (int)Math.Pow(1000, log);
                    // powStr will be thousand, million, billion etc.
                    powStr = thous[log];
                }

                // we take the quotient and the remainder after dividing by pow, and call ToWords on each to handle cases like "{five thousand} {thirty two}" (curly brackets added for emphasis)
                numString = string.Format(fmt_large_small, ToWords(number / pow, powStr), ToWords(number % pow)).Trim();
            }

            // and after all of this, if we were passed in a scale from above, we append it to the current number "{five} {thousand}"
            return string.Format(fmt_amount_scale, numString, appendScale).Trim();
        }
    }
    public class HelloWorld
    {
        // Main Class
        public static void Main()
        {
            static decimal ReadValue()
            {
                decimal resultVal;
                decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out resultVal);
                return resultVal;
            }

            Console.Write("Enter Numbers to convert to words: ");
            Money money = new Money(ReadValue());
            FromNumbers toWords = new FromNumbers();
            string text = toWords.ToWords(money.Paycheck);
            Console.WriteLine($"\n{text}\n");
        }
    }
}

//Output:
/*
 
    Enter Numbers to convert to words: 67.85

    sixty-seven dollars and eighty-five cents

*/
```

Comment: I would recommend using automatically-implemented properties - aside from anything else, it would avoid the typos you've got where setting every property actually sets the `fifty` field. (Easily done; I'm not trying to criticise you for that - just pointing out how using language features like auto-props can avoid similar issues.)

Comment: Good point, it would be better to incorporate a method in the class to populate the value that inputted through the constructor, right? Such as, I would think, a working programing in my mind would be input a numeric value and then output a verbal representation through a method. Thanks for the direction, appreciated it.

Comment: I didn't really look beyond "that looks like a lot of code for three properties - ah, and it's broken".

Comment: ok, I see you. https://www.programiz.com/csharp-programming/online-compiler/ works just fine.